# How to conditionally select a specific directory based on environment pom.xml

Tags: maven, conditional-statements, pom.xml

I have 2 files which are located in different directory. Based on the environment variable I need to select the files located in that respective directory.

For Example, I have required files for Non-production environment in  \src\main\resources\keystore\np-keystore
and required files for production environment in \src\main\resources\keystore\pd-keystore

Based on the env variable i need to select files located in these folders. How could I conditionally check and execute in my POM.xml

```
<profile>
   <id>prod</id>
   <activation>
      <property>
         <name>environment</name>
         <value>prod</value>
      </property>
   </activation>
</profile>
```

Will this activate my profile when I run on Prod environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<profile>
   <id>prod</id>
   <activation>
      <property>
         <name>env</name>
         <value>prod</value>
      </property>
   </activation>
</profile>
```

This actually works if you set your env variable either via Explicitly using command console input or Through maven settings.

So this profile will be activated depending upon the env variable specified. We can also use !Prod, to select all non-prod environments.